# mySQL query with JOIN on latest record not all records

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

The following code is used in a query for fetching records. It uses the electors.ID to find the corresponding voting_intention.elector from a second table.

```
$criteria = "FROM voting_intention,electors WHERE voting_intention.elector = electors.ID AND voting_intention.pledge IN ('C','P') AND electors.postal_vote = 1 AND electors.telephone > 0"
```

The problem is that some electors will have more than one pledge in the voting_intentions table.

I need it to match only on the latest `voting_intention.pledge` based on the field `votin_intention.date` for each elector.

What is the simplest way of implementing that.

The rest of the code:

```
function get_elector_phone($criteria){
    $the_elector = mysql_query("SELECT * $criteria ORDER BY electors.ID ASC"); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($the_elector)) { 
    echo $row['ID'].','; }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a sub-select with the `MAX()` function.  Add the following into your `WHERE` clause.

```
AND voting_intention.date = (select MAX(date) 
                         from voting_intention vote2 
                         where voting_intention.elector = vote2.elector)
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle of the results.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/73021/2)

Comment: A man talking my language. I didn't know there was an SQLFiddle thats very good

Comment: Yeah, just like JSFiddle.  I love to use it, because it lets me test my answers before just tossing them out there.  Plus, it lets the submitter verify the answer and even try out other changes.

Comment: One slight disclaimer... this answer does depend on individual electors not having multiple rows in the voting_intention table with the exact same date.  Based on your naming, I assumed that it was pretty unlikely.

Comment: Extremely unlikely. If it happened it would be because someone entered incorrectly.

Comment: We could be even safer though and add the time.

Answer (score 1):

So pretty much, you only want to bother looking at the most recent row that fits the first two criteria in your code. In that case, you would want to filter out the voting_intention table beforehand to only have to worry about the most recent entries of each. There's a question/answer that shows how do do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql).

Try selecting the following instead of voting_intention (from the answer of the linked question, some table and field names replaced):

```
SELECT voting_intention.*
FROM voting_intention
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT elector, MAX(date) AS MaxDate
FROM voting_intention
GROUP BY elector
) groupedintention ON voting_intention.elector = groupedintention.elector 
AND voting_intention.date = groupedintention .MaxDate
```

Question url: [How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)